# C++,QT Error When Assigning QList<T> to QList<T>

Tags: qt, struct, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am developing QML apps with c++ but I'm currently stuck with a, maybe simple, error:

> C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\QtCore\qvector.h:679: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'ListModel' and 'ListModel')
>            if (!(*--i == *--j))
>                       ^

My header is :

```
#ifndef COMBOBOXUPDATE_H
#define COMBOBOXUPDATE_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QString>
#include <QVector>

struct ListModel;

class ComboboxUpdate:public  QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QVector<ListModel> comboList READ comboList)

public:

  ComboboxUpdate(QObject *parent = 0);
  QVector<ListModel> comboList();
  void setComboList( QVector<ListModel> &comboList);

private:
QVector<ListModel> m_comboList;
int         m_count;
};

struct  ListModel
{
ListModel();
ListModel(QString _text,int _Sqlid)
{
    text=_text;
    Sqlid=_Sqlid;
}
QString text;
int     Sqlid;
};
#endif // COMBOBOXUPDATE_H
```

The error occurs in this code area inside implementation file:

```
void ComboboxUpdate::setComboList(  QVector<ListModel> &comboList)
{
    if (m_comboList != comboList)
    {
        m_comboList = comboList;
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why this problem occurs. My main target is filling combobox from c++ side using stuffs like `ListElement`. I can success to fill by using `QStringList`. But I want to fill by like `ListElement`. For example:

```
ComboBox {
    model: ListModel {
               ListElement {sqlid:"1"; text:"Pansi"}
               ListElement {sqlid:"2"; text:"Rose"}
               ListElement {sqlid:"3"; text:"Clips"}
           }
    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

On QML side this model shows text in `ComboBox` and stores the values into sqlite. How can I do that on c++ side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `operator==` for your class `ListModel`. For example:

```
struct  ListModel
{
    bool operator==(const ListModel& other) const {
        return other.text == text && other.Sqlid == Sqlid;
    }
};
```